# CSVHelper BadDataFound in a valid csv

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Our customer started reporting bugs with importing data from CSV file. After seeing the csv file, we decided to switch from custom CSV parser to CSVHelper, but the CSV Helper can't read some valid CSV files.

The users are able to load any csv file into our application, so we can't use any class mapper. We use csv.Parser.Read to read string[] dataRows. We can't change a way how this csv file is generated, it is generated by another company and we can't convince them to change the generation when this file is in a valid format.

If we youse BadDataFound handler, the context.RawRecord is:

```
"1000084;SMRSTOVACI TRUBICE PBF 12,7/6,4 (1/2\") H;"
```

the data row in csv file is:

```
1000084;SMRSTOVACI TRUBICE PBF 12,7/6,4 (1/2") H;;;ks;21,59;26,46;21.00;;;8591735015183;8591735015183;Technik;Kabelový spojovací materiál;Označování, smršťování, izolace;Bužírky, smršťovačky;
```

This should be a valid csv file by RFC 4180.

The code is:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        List<string> badRecord = new List<string>();
        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context => badRecord.Add(context.RawRecord);

        header = csv.Context.HeaderRecord.ToList();

        while (true)
        {
            var dataRow = csv.Parser.Read();
            if (dataRow == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            data.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to configure CSVHelper to be able to load this row to string[]? Or can you suggest different parse which will be able to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I believe it is the quote in the middle of the row that is causing the issue.  Try setting the configuration to ignore quotes.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
        csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true;

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        List<string> badRecord = new List<string>();
        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context => badRecord.Add(context.RawRecord);

        header = csv.Context.HeaderRecord.ToList();

        while (true)
        {
            var dataRow = csv.Parser.Read();
            if (dataRow == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            data.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated for version 27.2.1**

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    List<string> badRecord = new List<string>();
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = ";",
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape,
        BadDataFound = context => badRecord.Add(context.RawRecord)
    };
    
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        header = csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord.ToList();

        while (csv.Parser.Read())
        {           
            data.Add(csv.Parser.Record);
        }
    }
}
```