# Download CSV file using HttpClient and Process with CsvHelper onfly

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to download a csv file using HttpClient and process using CsvHelper library

```
string url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/allIndices?csv=true";
string useragent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36";

var httpclient = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var sendtask = httpclient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var response = sendtask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(httpStream);

CsvReader futureoptionsreader = new CsvReader(streamreader, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
futureoptionsreader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MappingNSEIndexes>();
var list = futureoptionsreader.GetRecords<RawNSEIndexes>();
var number = list.Count();
```

Ended with bad data error

```
CsvHelper.BadDataException: You can ignore bad data by setting BadDataFound to null.
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecords[T]()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MIS.Equity.API.Controllers.BooksController.GetCompaniesAsync() in C:\Users\Ramesh\source\repos\MIS_Main\MarkertInfoSystem\MIS.Equity.API\Controllers\BooksController.cs:line 66
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
```

is this approach correct ? thanks in advance

Comment: You have 2 problems, download the file, and process the csv, have you saved the csv data to file and checked it is actually a csv? If it is, then you only have one problem... But we cant tell what it is, only you

Comment: There are. *lot* of problems with this code, but the error complains about the *data*, not the code. Have you checked what the file contains? The headers are rather ... weird.

Comment: @TheGeneral - I am not trying to download csv file to my system, I am trying to do it on fly loading to CsvHepler.

Comment: Not a huge mistake but you're blocking current Thread while getting a response, fix: `var response = (await sendtask).EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`. And you've totally ignored `IDisposable`s, that's really bad if you want to run that code more than once per application life. About BadData, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55184738/12888024).

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the structure of the CSV file. the header (with the fieldnames) contains a line break after every fieldname ...

Answer (score 0):

So, the code you posted is a tad off... I couldn't get it to compile so I re-wrote it to follow a common pattern when using the `HttpClient`:

```
var url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/allIndices?csv=true";

using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url)))
{
    msg.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/csv"));
    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using (var s = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
        using (var futureoptionsreader = new CsvReader(sr, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            futureoptionsreader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MappingNSEIndexes>();
            var list = futureoptionsreader.GetRecords<RawNSEIndexes>();
            var number = list.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, the server will not return any data unless you add the `Headers.Accept` line.

One of the major issues is this line:

```
var response = sendtask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

That doesn't even compile -- `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` returns `void`. So I am assuming you copy and pasted code after you had modified it trying to troubleshoot.